# npm “error network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org”

Tags: linux, node.js, npm, arm

I have cross compile node.js (v0.12.8) with npm (v2.14.9) for ARM cortex-A5 correctly. If i run node.js example hello world work successfully.

But when i try install any package via npm the result is ever:

`npm ERR! network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org`

Follow complete debug info:

```
root@myboard:/# npm install -g forever -d
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@2.14.9
npm info using node@v0.12.8
npm info attempt registry request try #1 at 19:05:56
npm http request GET http://registry.npmjs.org/forever
npm info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org
npm info attempt registry request try #2 at 19:06:06
npm http request GET http://registry.npmjs.org/forever
npm info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org
npm info attempt registry request try #3 at 19:07:06
npm http request GET http://registry.npmjs.org/forever
npm ERR! Linux 3.18.23
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "forever" "-d"
npm ERR! node v0.12.8
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.9
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo

npm ERR! network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /npm-debug.log
root@myboard:/#
root@myboard:/# ping registry.npmjs.org
PING registry.npmjs.org (185.31.17.162): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 185.31.17.162: seq=0 ttl=54 time=64.314 ms
64 bytes from 185.31.17.162: seq=1 ttl=54 time=64.403 ms
64 bytes from 185.31.17.162: seq=2 ttl=56 time=64.846 ms
^C
--- registry.npmjs.org ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 64.314/64.521/64.846 ms
root@myboard:/#
```

In stackoverflow or google i have found information about this problem but all say about proxy configuration but i don't use any proxy because myboard is connect directly to router with cable and is still connect to internet.
In example i can ping correctly host: `registry.npmjs.org` but npm not recognize.

I also tried without success set npm config:

`npm config set strict-ssl false`

`npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/`

I hope exsist any solution about this problem.

Comment: I have try compile and install another nodejs version (v0.10.41) and another npm version (v1.4.29). All work successfully. I can not understand what's wrong with node version (v0.12.8) and npm version (v2.14.9)

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and it was an issue with my hosts file having the entry

```
185.31.17.162    registry.npmjs.org
```

Once I deleted that, everything worked perfectly. It was a workaround I had added during October 2016 DYN attack.